# About a norm : $p(uv)=p(u)p(v)$ all the time?

Tags: inequality, vector-spaces, definition, normed-spaces

Say, $p$ is a norm on a vector space.

Then can we say that

$$p(uv)=p(u)p(v)$$ all the time?

Thanks.

Comment: What does mean $uv$? Are both of them vectors?

Comment: Yes. u,v are vectors.

Comment: How do you define $uv$?

Comment: My actual question is that for Banach valued functions f,g, if the norm of the pointwise product f*g is equal to the norm of f times the norm of g.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the obvious difficulty to make sense of vector-times-vector multiplication, there are vector spaces, where the inequality is true: $V=\mathbb R$ or $V=\mathbb C$.

It fails however for matrices. Take for instance
$$
A=\pmatrix{0 & 1\\ 0& 0 }.
$$
Take any matrix norm. Then $\|A\|\ne0$, as  $A\ne0$. However it holds $A^2=0$,
hence
$$
0 = \|A\cdot A\| \ne \|A\|\cdot\|A\| = \|A\|^2 .
$$

Comment: Then can we always say that the norm of the product of two vectors is less than or equal to the norm of a vector times the norm of the other vector regardless of how a norm and a product are defined?

Answer (score 0):

Norm p is a map from a vector space V to the reals R. Assuming uv is the inner product (which maps VxV to some set of scalars S) then p(uv) is only defined when V = S. In that case you would have something like p(uv)=|uv| and p(u)p(v)=|u||v|. Otherwise p(uv) is not really defined for more general vector spaces.

Comment: Oh I see it. Thanks.

Comment: No prob. It just works for a specific case.